# SSL error when connecting to a SQL Server database via ODBC from ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database via ODBC using Microsoft's ODBC driver 17.

The `odbc.ini` file contains:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
MyDB=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

[MyDB]
Description=MyDB test database
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Server=***.***.***.***
Port=1433
Database=DbName
UID=********
PWD=********
Encrypt = no
TrustServerCertificate = no
Security = TLSv1
```

The database parameters are verified and correct.

The `odbcinst.ini` file contains:

```
[Default]
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.2.1

[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.2.so.1.1
UsageCount=1

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
```

The code used to connect is the following (python):

```
import pyodbc
def connect():
    connStr = 'DSN=MyDB;'
    print(f'Connection: {connStr}')
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
    cur1 = cnxn.execute('SELECT top 2 * from MASTER')
    res1 = cur1.fetchall()
    print(res1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     connect()
```

And the result from this is:

```
Connection: DSN=MyDB
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.869580][__handles.c][460]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Environment = 0x557e51cc9e80
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.869650][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][189]
        Entry:
            Environment = 0x557e51cc9e80
            Attribute = SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION
            Value = 0x3
            StrLen = 4
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.869720][SQLSetEnvAttr.c][381]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.869746][SQLAllocHandle.c][377]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x557e51cc9e80
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF-8' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'

[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.869836][SQLAllocHandle.c][513]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Output Handle = 0x557e51ce8a80
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.870183][SQLDriverConnectW.c][290]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x557e51ce8a80
            Window Hdl = (nil)
            Str In = [DSN=MyDB][length = 8 (SQL_NTS)]
            Str Out = (nil)
            Str Out Max = 0
            Str Out Ptr = (nil)
            Completion = 0
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.879971][__handles.c][460]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Environment = 0x557e51d30ce0
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.880053][SQLGetEnvAttr.c][157]
        Entry:
            Environment = 0x557e51d30ce0
            Attribute = 65002
            Value = 0x7fffaef27420
            Buffer Len = 128
            StrLen = 0x7fffaef273bc
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.880185][SQLGetEnvAttr.c][273]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.880229][SQLFreeHandle.c][220]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 1
            Input Handle = 0x557e51d30ce0
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.880360][SQLDriverConnectW.c][699]
        Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.880402][SQLDriverConnect.c][748]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x557e51ce8a80
            Window Hdl = (nil)
            Str In = [DSN=MyDB][length = 8 (SQL_NTS)]
            Str Out = 0x7fffaef2b190
            Str Out Max = 2048
            Str Out Ptr = (nil)
            Completion = 0
        DIAG [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A0C0103:SSL routines::internal error]

        DIAG [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection

[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.884482][SQLDriverConnect.c][1637]
        Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.884519][SQLGetDiagRecW.c][535]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x557e51ce8a80
            Rec Number = 1
            SQLState = 0x7fffaef2c994
            Native = 0x7fffaef2c96c
            Message Text = 0x557e51d98250
            Buffer Length = 1023
            Text Len Ptr = 0x7fffaef2c96a
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.884612][SQLGetDiagRecW.c][596]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            SQLState = [08001]
            Native = 0x7fffaef2c96c -> -1 (32 bits)
            Message Text = [[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A0C0103:SSL routines::internal error]]
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.884703][SQLFreeHandle.c][290]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x557e51ce8a80
[ODBC][2133819][1678232108.884753][SQLFreeHandle.c][339]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/data2.py", line 13, in <module>
    connect()
  File "/home/data2.py", line 7, in connect
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A0C0103:SSL routines::internal error] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the issue was fixed by adding the following at the bottom of the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf file:

```
[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0
```